# Getting lot of ANR in Accessiblity Service Due to Thread Pool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I'm getting lot of ANR for accessibility service due to Thread blocks. Right now I'm clueless through the logs which I went. Looking for someone's help, Please see the below logs in details :

```
07/17/2019, 10:02 PM on app version 51001044 executing service com.jarvis.android.accessiblity.vms/com.jarvis.monitor.JMSAccessibilityService
com.jarvis.monitor.JMSAccessibilityService
P00I, Android 7.0
Report 1 of 3


COLLAPSE ALL
"main" tid=1 Native 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7569ca30 self=0x7fb0496a00
| sysTid=12275 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb4432a98
| state=S schedstat=( 199775252 38456357 213 ) utm=11 stm=8 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7ff5a0f000-0x7ff5a11000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a82c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
#01  pc 000000000001e4e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
#02  pc 0000000000018080  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
#03  pc 0000000000017f34  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
#04  pc 00000000000ee894  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
#05  pc 00000000008ae260  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6130)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=2 Native 
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
| group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7fa880d000
| sysTid=12281 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fafb0d450
| state=S schedstat=( 149518583 65905890 344 ) utm=11 stm=3 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fafa0f000-0x7fafa11000 stackSize=1021KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000001c0ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 00000000000e6dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+160)
#02  pc 0000000000463cbc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+252)
#03  pc 0000000000463178  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+124)
#04  pc 0000000000462aa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
#05  pc 0000000000068490  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
#06  pc 000000000001ddb0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting 
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05160 self=0x7faf410600
| sysTid=12284 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf90f450
| state=S schedstat=( 1553282 735937 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf80d000-0x7faf80f000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0326ed6a> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run (Daemons.java:150)
- locked <0x0326ed6a> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=5 Waiting 
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c051f0 self=0x7fb0497e00
| sysTid=12286 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf705450
| state=S schedstat=( 440575 39219 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf603000-0x7faf605000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0de5925b> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded (Daemons.java:269)
- locked <0x0de5925b> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run (Daemons.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"FinalizerDaemon" tid=7 Waiting 
"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Waiting
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05310 self=0x7fb0497400
| sysTid=12285 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf80a450
| state=S schedstat=( 5019948 9021979 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf708000-0x7faf70a000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0ab93af8> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:407)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:188)
- locked <0x0ab93af8> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:209)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:204)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"Binder:12275_1" tid=8 Native 
"Binder:12275_1" prio=5 tid=8 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c053a0 self=0x7fa8818400
| sysTid=12288 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf1fc450
| state=S schedstat=( 3750314 8551042 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf102000-0x7faf104000 stackSize=1005KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a918  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
#01  pc 000000000001fd30  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+144)
#02  pc 0000000000055534  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+260)
#03  pc 0000000000055694  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24)
#04  pc 0000000000055dc0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+72)
#05  pc 0000000000072dc4  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???)
#06  pc 0000000000012488  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
#07  pc 000000000009ea28  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
#08  pc 0000000000068490  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
#09  pc 000000000001ddb0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
"Binder:12275_2" tid=9 Native 
"Binder:12275_2" prio=5 tid=9 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05430 self=0x7fb04c2200
| sysTid=12289 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf0ff450
| state=S schedstat=( 3308334 8329531 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf005000-0x7faf007000 stackSize=1005KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a918  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
#01  pc 000000000001fd30  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+144)
#02  pc 0000000000055534  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+260)
#03  pc 0000000000055694  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24)
#04  pc 0000000000055dc0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+72)
#05  pc 0000000000072dc4  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???)
#06  pc 0000000000012488  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
#07  pc 000000000009ea28  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
#08  pc 0000000000068490  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
#09  pc 000000000001ddb0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
"Profile Saver" tid=10 Native 
"Profile Saver" daemon prio=5 tid=10 Native
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c054c0 self=0x7fa882f800
| sysTid=12290 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf002450
| state=S schedstat=( 9889328 7658018 26 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faef08000-0x7faef0a000 stackSize=1005KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000001c0ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 00000000000e6dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+160)
#02  pc 0000000000319e70  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver3RunEv+296)
#03  pc 000000000031b588  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver21RunProfileSaverThreadEPv+100)
#04  pc 0000000000068490  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
#05  pc 000000000001ddb0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
"FirebaseInstanceId" tid=11 Waiting 
"FirebaseInstanceId" prio=5 tid=11 Waiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05550 self=0x7faf467400
| sysTid=12294 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faee0e450
| state=S schedstat=( 6156873 3139690 20 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faed0c000-0x7faed0e000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x04a5dbd1> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x04a5dbd1> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (unavailable)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"firebase-iid-executor" tid=12 TimedWaiting 
"firebase-iid-executor" prio=5 tid=12 TimedWaiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c055e0 self=0x7faf436600
| sysTid=12295 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa8ec3450
| state=S schedstat=( 306236043 14206771 58 ) utm=28 stm=2 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fa8dc1000-0x7fa8dc3000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x083e7636> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x083e7636> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"Measurement Worker" tid=13 TimedWaiting 
"Measurement Worker" prio=5 tid=13 TimedWaiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05670 self=0x7faf467e00
| sysTid=12296 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa8d97450
| state=S schedstat=( 96849686 144578650 273 ) utm=6 stm=3 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fa8c95000-0x7fa8c97000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0e60f937> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:407)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbv.run (unavailable)
"firebase-iid-executor" tid=15 TimedWaiting 
"firebase-iid-executor" prio=5 tid=15 TimedWaiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05790 self=0x7fa8844c00
| sysTid=12385 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f941f5450
| state=S schedstat=( 9927708 972501 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f940f3000-0x7f940f5000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x02c30ea4> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x02c30ea4> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"BackgroundWorker - HandlerThread-1" tid=16 Native 
"BackgroundWorker - HandlerThread-1" daemon prio=5 tid=16 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0b100 self=0x7fa8845600
| sysTid=12312 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f942fa450
| state=S schedstat=( 11037242 13776667 32 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f941f8000-0x7f941fa000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a82c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
#01  pc 000000000001e4e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
#02  pc 0000000000018080  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
#03  pc 0000000000017f34  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
#04  pc 00000000000ee894  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
#05  pc 00000000008ae260  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:139)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.jarvis.android.concurrent.BackgroundWorker$BgHandlerThread.run (unavailable)
"pool-2-thread-1" tid=17 Waiting 
"pool-2-thread-1" prio=5 tid=17 Waiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05820 self=0x7faf4bea00
| sysTid=12387 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f943ff450
| state=S schedstat=( 17024011 9742865 73 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f942fd000-0x7f942ff000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x025b640d> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x025b640d> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"MessengerIpcClient" tid=18 TimedWaiting 
"MessengerIpcClient" prio=5 tid=18 TimedWaiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c058b0 self=0x7faf4be000
| sysTid=12390 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f940f0450
| state=S schedstat=( 1294688 2890000 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f93fee000-0x7f93ff0000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0873bfc2> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x0873bfc2> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (unavailable)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
"ConnectivityManager" tid=20 Native 
"ConnectivityManager" daemon prio=5 tid=20 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c059d0 self=0x7fa88ca800
| sysTid=12560 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f93c46450
| state=S schedstat=( 981199 1553072 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f93b44000-0x7f93b46000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a82c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
#01  pc 000000000001e4e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
#02  pc 0000000000018080  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
#03  pc 0000000000017f34  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
#04  pc 00000000000ee894  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
#05  pc 00000000008ae260  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:139)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
"TopAppMonitor - HandlerThread-2" tid=33 Native 
"TopAppMonitor - HandlerThread-2" daemon prio=5 tid=33 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0b1a0 self=0x7f9390e600
| sysTid=12652 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8651b450
| state=S schedstat=( 451406 1863958 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7f86419000-0x7f8641b000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006a82c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
#01  pc 000000000001e4e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
#02  pc 0000000000018080  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
#03  pc 0000000000017f34  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
#04  pc 00000000000ee894  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
#05  pc 00000000008ae260  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:139)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.jarvis.android.concurrent.BackgroundWorker$BgHandlerThread.run (unavailable)
"Signal Catcher" tid=3 Runnable 
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Runnable
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c050d0 self=0x7faf40c000
| sysTid=12283 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fafa0c450
| state=R schedstat=( 66476658 30308337 224 ) utm=0 stm=6 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf912000-0x7faf914000 stackSize=1005KB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
#00  pc 0000000000475fe0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
#01  pc 0000000000475fdc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
#02  pc 000000000044a828  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+472)
#03  pc 0000000000461f48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+820)
#04  pc 000000000045a228  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+456)
#05  pc 0000000000459e38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+288)
#06  pc 0000000000459cd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+804)
#07  pc 0000000000435e80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+344)
#08  pc 000000000043c538  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13HandleSigQuitEv+2240)
#09  pc 000000000043b060  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+476)
#10  pc 0000000000068490  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
#11  pc 000000000001ddb0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
"HeapTaskDaemon" tid=6 Blocked 
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c05280 self=0x7fb0498800
| sysTid=12287 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf3ff450
| state=S schedstat=( 118446977 11305053 57 ) utm=11 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
| stack=0x7faf2fd000-0x7faf2ff000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000001c0ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 00000000000e6dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+160)
#02  pc 000000000023f3fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+360)
#03  pc 000000000023fcd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
#04  pc 00000000001e50a0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+124)
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
- waiting to lock an unknown object
at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run (Daemons.java:433)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

Any help will be appreciated..